When to apply cold temperature correction?
I am having trouble understanding when to apply cold temperature correction, I have heard about the below 0 deg Celsius rule but I could not find any of this in official regulations such as 8168 or FAA AIM chapter 7 section 3.
If someone knows the answer please support your answer with some official reg, ideally EASA or ICAO.

May or may not answer your question, but this thread has background info. These corrections typically don't apply until the temperature is well below 0 degrees C.

It is common (in Europe, probably elsewhere) for commercial pilots to cold temperature correct all altitudes that are lower or equal to the MSA when the airport temperature is 0°C or below, in accordance with their company’s standard operating procedures.
For example if the MSA is 5000ft we would cold temperature adjust all altitudes in our CDU at or below 5000ft and also add a cold temperature adjustment to the minimums (DA/MDA).
Skybrary provides a downloadable Excel file calculator tool, which might be useful as a helpful demonstration to show you how to make these corrections.
The regulations are described in ICAO Doc 8168 (PANS-OPS) - Section 2 Chapter 4, 4.3 (including table 2-4-1). Though these cold temp corrections may typically also be referenced in the Flight Crew Operations Manual (FCOM) which is practically where pilots would go to find a reference and make calculations (tables would be available like this). For the Boeing 737, it is listed as a supplementary procure (SP) in the FCOM, in the Adverse Weather section.
There will be temperature restrictions on some approaches, such as RNP approaches.
Further information in Skybrary

ICAO Doc 8168 says "The calculated minimum safe altitudes/heights must be adjusted when the ambient temperature on the surface is much lower than that predicted by the standard atmosphere." I don't know what the regulation mean by using the term 'much lower' is it defined more precisely somewhere else?
